# Does JRebel works with any process?

Tags: jrebel

If I have a standalone application with several processes running, can I use JRebel to publish changes in my code without killing any of the processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But only if this is a deployment in development environment. EULA restricts the user for live deployments.